# CSS borders in Hotmail

Tags: html, css, email, hotmail

I have created a HTML email that displays fine in all the email clients I have tested it in, expect for Hotmail. Hotmail for some reason, is stripping my css border styles and not displaying them.

I have included part of the code that has the border on it:

```
<td bgcolor="white" width="121" style="background: #ffffff; height: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid lightgray; border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;">TEST DATA</td>
```

I have put the styling on the TD, but it is not showing up. I have also tried the below code, but this does not work either:

```
    <td bgcolor="white" width="121" style="background: #ffffff; height: 25px; border-bottom: 1px solid; border-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);">TEST DATA</td>
```

Does anyone know how to get CSS borders to display in Hotmail as the are displaying fine in other email clients.

Any help would be gratefully recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Put a DIV in the TD and style the DIV instead.

Here is a handy guide on Email CSS restrictions:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what I have done. I tried to put the div in the td like this: <td><div style="border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;">DATA</div></td>, but it still did not work in Hotmail. This is the only email client that the border does not work in.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to use none of the short-hand border styling, e.g. instead of:

```
border-bottom:1px solid;
```

Try

```
border-bottom-width:1px;
border-bottom-style: solid;
```

Comment: I have now tried this: <td style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #dcdcdc; border-bottom-style: solid;">DATA</td>, but it still is not working in Hotmail. Does anyone know of anything else that I can try?

Comment: Instead of writing the color in hex (#dcdcdc), I tried writing it in words (lightgray). The borders now work in Hotmail, but have stopped working in Outlook 2010.

Comment: >< someone needs to explain to Microsoft what 'consistent' means..!

Answer (score 0):

try: border="1"

Does that work in hotmail?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the border solutions are working, have you tried making a "fake" border using the CSS background property? It's a cosmetic work around.

```
background: #fff url('fakeBorder.gif') no-repeat right;
```

Hope this helps.